# ASP.NET internationalization falls back to English instead of default language file

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization

I'm building a Norwegian website, which will receive some foreign visitors also. Since most Scandinavians can read Norwegian, this will be the default language. (I.e., *.resx is in Norwegian.) Only for our Finnish and English visitors, I create separate resources (*.fi.resx and *.en.resx).

However, to my big shock, *all visitors except the Finnish* are seeing the English text! I've been testing this myself, and I can reproduce the problem in various webbrowsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera), trying various language preferences, and making sure English is *not* one of them.

Why is the fall-back resource file (*.resx) never loaded? According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx), the fall-back file should be loaded when there is no language file available for the specified language.

Comment: If you do some debugging and check the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` in your Page_Load (or in your controller if using MVC), what do you see? It sounds like ASP.NET has chosen an English culture, hence you're not getting the resource fallback since English resources are present.

Comment: @Peter: What is the technology you are using precisely? Plain Asp.Net or Asp.Net MVC? What version (of .Net Framework for example)? I'd suspect incorrect settings or lack of uiCulture assignment (in plain Asp.Net try `uiCulture="auto:no"`).

Comment: I'm using plain ASP.NET (with resource files in App_LocalResources), version 4.0. Checking CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture returns the expected cultures (e.g. when using "nb-no" in the browser it returns "nb-NO" and "nb" as cultures, when using "en" it returns "en-US" and "en"). However, when using obscure languages (e.g. Afar [aa]) it gets more interesting: on VS's Development Server it returns "nb-NO" and "no", on IIS 7.5 it returns "nb-NO" for CurrentCulture and "en-US" (!) for CurrentUICulture. Still, in all cases, the .en.resx resource file is used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these setting in web.config?

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableclientbasedculture="true" uiculture="auto" culture="auto">
    </globalization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Yes, I have those values in my web.config (note: the [globalization Element page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) on MSDN says that "This attribute is not in use at this time.")